# JWTAuth getToken give false result when tried to call it in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm new in laravel and get stuck already with JWTAuth service in laravel. 
I'm developing mobile app using ionic and try to make request to generate jwt token. It turn out I was able to generate the token, but when I try another request to compare the token, I cannot get the token using JWTAuth::getToken() in the laravel.

here my script for signin (generate token)

```
   public function signin(Request $request){
     $request = [
        'email'    => urldecode($request->request->get('email')),
        'password' => urldecode($request->request->get('password'))
    ];   

    if(Auth::attempt($request)){

        $user   = Auth::user();
        Auth::login($user, true);
        $custom = ['id' => $user->id, 'email' => $user->email, 'fullname' => $user->name];

        $newToken = JWTAuth::fromUser($user,$custom);
        $return = array('success' => true, 'token' => $newToken);
    }else{
        $return = array('success' => false,'token' => '');
    };
    return response()->json($return);
}
```

and this is another method to get the token from laravel

```
public function signout($token){

    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user){
        $return = array('success' => false,'token' => JWTAuth::getToken());
    }else{
        $return = array('success' => false,'token' => $token);
    }

    return response()->json($return);
}
```

is there anyone experience same problem with me? or I missed something here? thanks for the answer and help!